# Многопоточность synchronized

Tags: java, многопоточность

На сколько мне известно ключевое слово `synchronize`, в десятки если не сотни раз замедляет выполнение метода, чем обусловлен такой колоссальный проигрыш в скорости, и есть ли какие-либо аналоги синхронизации потоков?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проигрыш возникает только в многопоточной среде, на одном потоке разницы нет. Дело в том, что для выполнения `synchronized` блока, все потоки должны дойти до места его начала, а далее по очереди выполнить `synchronized` блок на одном потоке.

Однозначно ответить на вопрос про аналоги синхронизации не получится, вопрос слишком общий и в зависимости от данных и реализации сильно варьируется, есть блокирующие алгоритмы, есть неблокирующие, транзакционная память. В данном случае уже надо разбираться в конкретной задаче, представлении данных и способе их обработки, в идеале все данные должны обрабатываться независимо, тогда и синхронизировать потоки не потребуется.

Answer (score 6):

Как уже заметили авторы других ответов, основная причина замедления в том, что синхронизированный метод/блок может выполнять только один поток за раз, а другим приходиться ждать. Но есть и другие факторы, который вносят куда меньший вклад в замедление, но всё же могут быть заметны в алгоритмах с высокими требованиями к производительности. Первый такой фактор - это накладные расходы на операции захвата/освобождения монитора. Для *biased* монитора они минимальны - укладываются в несколько аппаратных инструкций, но при высоком *contention* виртуальной машине приходится выполнять существенно больше действий. В том числе действий с участием системных вызовов, что приводит к переключению контекста. Второй фактор - это *safepoint'ы*. В случае HotSpot они могут быть только глобальными, поэтому *раздувание/сдувание* монитора на мгновение останавливает абсолютно все потоки JVM, включая сервисные. Третий фактор, ещё более низкоуровневый - это необходимость использовать *memory barrier* при захвате монитора. Это снижает возможности по оптимизации *reordering'ом* и заставляет процессоры заниматься синхронизацией кэш-памяти.

Поэтому при написании многопоточных программ так важно по максимуму снизить использование разделённого состояния или сделать его неизменяемым. *Immutability* и *confinement* - лучшие альтернативы синхронизации.

Answer (score 2):

*Блокировка защищает сегмент кода, позволяя только одному потоку в единицу времени выполнять этот код.

Блокировка управляет потоками, которые пытаются войти в защищенный сегмент кода.

Каждый объект условия управляет потоками, вошедшими в защищенный сегмент кода, но которые пока не в состоянии выполнять работу.*

Чем дольше выполняется блок кода,  доступ к которому потоки должны получать по очереди, тем хуже. НО если это действительно такой код, с которым нельзя работать одновременно с нескольких потоков, то иного выхода нет. Надо синхронизировать. Ключевое слово `synchronize` это просто удобный инструмент от Java. Если очень много подобного кода, то лучше использовать более гибкие инструменты. 
Интерфейсы `Lock` и `Condition` были добавлены в Java SE 5.0, чтобы предоставить программистам высокую степень контроля блокировок.
Так же в Java есть ключевое слово `volatile` , которое разрешает с переменной работать одновременно одному потоку. 
О некоторых подводных камнях можно прочитать [здесь](https://habr.com/post/108016/) И так же хорошая [статья](http://pro-java.ru/java-dlya-opytnyx/klyuchevoe-slovo-synchronized-java/) из которой можно понять о том как всё это работает.

[Слово synchronized в Java "на пальцах"](https://gist.github.com/Ari100tell/9577906)

Думаю должно быть понятно, что если это сервер к которому обращаются тысячи клиентов и есть некий элемент, который нельзя менять одновременно нескольким клиентам, то придется становиться в очередь. То же самое, если это приложение, в котором к блоку кода обращаются, например, 8 потоков. Блок кода, допустим выполняется за 1 сек. Все потоки вместо пройдут его чуть больше, чем за 8 сек.  Это конечно такое не точное объяснение, но этого пока достаточно. Просто стоит знать, что если нужна синхронизация , то это либо использование `synchronize`, которое оставит код читабельнее, но воздействует глобально, возможно, и на участки кода, где синхронизация не нужна. Либо использовать другие инструменты для точечного воздействия.