# Java и synchronized в однопоточной среде

Tags: java, synchronized

Всем привет!

Подскажите пожалуйста, часто пишут что методы использующие оператор *synchronized* являются медленными и для многопоточной среды это понятно. Потоки как будто выстраиваются в ряд и ждут своей очереди, но как это может повлиять на работу когда запущен только один - главный поток, а других претендентов нет?

Comment: Вам может быть интересен [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/847251/204271).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Конечно же ничего не бывает бесплатно.**

> **synchronized метод** отмечается на уровне структуры method_info флагом ACC_SYNCHRONIZED и байт-код от этого не сильно вырастает

метод:

```
public synchronized int top1(){
  return intArr[0];
}
```

байт код:

```
Method int top1()
   0 aload_0 
   1 getfield #6 <Field int intArr[]>
   4 iconst_0      
   5 iaload         
   6 ireturn
```

---

> **synchronized блок** же будет содержать инструкции синхронизации

метод:

```
public int top2(){
 synchronized (this) {
  return intArr[0];
 }
}
```

байт-код:

```
Method int top2()
   0 aload_0    
   1 astore_2               
   2 aload_2         
   3 monitorenter           
   4 aload_0                
   5 getfield #6 <Field int intArr[]>
   8 iconst_0         
   9 iaload                       
  10 istore_1                       
  11 jsr 19                     
  14 iload_1                           
  15 ireturn                           
  16 aload_2                           
  17 monitorexit                     
  18 athrow                        
  19 astore_3                     
  20 aload_2                 
  21 monitorexit             
  22 ret 3
```

---

Как видно добавление synchronized блоков точно замедлит выполнение этих участков больше чем synchronized методы.

[Подробнее о том, как работает синхронизация](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Implicit_condition_monitors)

Comment: Спасибо, стало понятнее.

Comment: @Антон всегда пожалуйста